# Call Excel Add-In function in macro

Tags: c#, vba, excel, excel-addins

I am developing Add-in for Excel 2013 and I have created a function in Excel Add-In as below

```
  public string ExcelReturnString()
    {
        return "This is the string: hi";
    }
```

I have used below code to call the function, but it throws an error.

```
Application.Run(ExcelReturnString)
```

How can I call the Add-in function in macro?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is about the farthest thing from straight-forward, but this is how you accomplish the task.  I'm going to be as explicit as possible, because the first two or three times I tried to do this, I missed a LOT.

First, when you create the class that hosts `ExcelReturnString()`, you need to decorate the class with an interface that has the following attributes and then also tag the attributes for each method you want to expose.  I made the add-in class "TestExcelAddIn" for the sake of this example:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace TestExcelAddIn
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface IStringGetter
    {
        string ExcelReturnString();
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class StringGetter : IStringGetter
    {
        public string ExcelReturnString()
        {
            return "This is the string: hi";
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the main class, associated with "Excel" in your project, you have to override `RequestComAddInAutomationService` in the following manner.  Again, I am including EVERYTHING so you know which class is which (I didn't when I first read it).

```
namespace TestExcelAddIn
{
    public partial class ExcelTest
    {
        private StringGetter myAddIn;

        protected override object RequestComAddInAutomationService()
        {
            if (myAddIn == null)
                myAddIn = new StringGetter();

            return myAddIn;
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO generated code
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Now VBA is ready to consume this method in the following manner:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim addin As Office.COMAddIn
    Dim automationObject As Object
    Dim returnString As String

    Set addin = Application.COMAddIns("TestExcelAddIn")
    Set automationObject = addin.Object

    returnString = automationObject.ExcelReturnString

End Sub
```

You could have given me 100 years to figure this out, and I would not have.  Actually credit MSDN for the Rosetta stone on it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608621.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thanks Hambone for your reply. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to DaveMac's note above, also keep in mind a couple of points when calling another routine:

If you're calling a macro from a routine that resides in the same workbook/addin as that routine, you don't have to use Application.Run. You can just call it by using its name:

```
MyMacro
```

If you're calling a macro that is in a different workbook, then you do need to use Application.Run, but you will also want to use the workbook name where the macro resides, otherwise VBA will not know where it should look for the macro:

```
Application.Run "'My Fancy Spreadsheet.xlsm!'MyMacro"
```

Comment: Not to beat this dead horse, but the method is within a COM add-in, not within the VBA project...

Answer (score -3):

Your code appears to be java.

Excel uses Visual basic, for example.

```
Function excelreturnstring()
    excelreturnstring = "this is the string: hi"
End function
```

Comment: The OP was talking about an Add-in, which appears to be C# in this case.  The actual method was a trivial one, to demonstrate that he cannot access the add-in methods from VBA -- I don't think he really wanted to know how to code this particular function in VBA