# VBA Compile error: Argument not optional when calling a method from a COM AddIn

Tags: excel, vba, com, excel-addins

I have the following code:

```
Sub CallVSTOMethod()
    Dim addin As COMAddIns
    Dim automationObject As Object
    Set addin = Application.COMAddIns("CssFillTool")
    Set automationObject = addin.Item
    automationObject.ButtonClearRemarks
End Sub
```

I am trying to find out why i am getting this error.

ButtonClearRemarks is one of many macros in the addin. when i click that macro seperately it works properly.

This macro does not require any argument. This on clicking will format my excelsheet. I tried passing empty arguments and other options as well, but no use. any suggestions are welcome.

After few corrections : 
        `Set addin = Application.COMAddIns 
         Set automationObject = addin.Item("CssFillTool")`

now i just need to access the macro`ButtonClearRemarks` within this Add-ins

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't the line above which is throwing the error? `Item` sounds like a method which requires an argument.

Comment: @JohnColeman Yes ! i changed the code as:                                           Set addin = Application.COMAddIns
Set automationObject = addin.Item("CssFillTool") Now this does not throw any error. But now i don't know the syntax to call the "ButtonClearRemarks" macro. the next line is now throwing error : object does't suppot this property or method

Comment: Should it be `Set automationObject = addin.Object`?

Comment: The help says "Required Object. Either an ordinal value that returns the COM add-in at that position in the COMAddIns collection, or a String value that represents the ProgID of the specified COM add-in." And it looks like it returns a `COMAddIn` . This is not VBA but should give advice: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.core.comaddins.item?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=office-pia#Microsoft_Office_Core_COMAddIns_Item_System_Object__

Comment: So, shouldn't you assign `addins` as the return value of `Application.COMAddIns()` and then access the one you are interested in via the item index?

Comment: Try using “call” use Call automationObject.buttonClearRemarks

Comment: @TanmayGawankar No! this is throwing an error _Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438)_ . Not only if i use _call_, also if this is used_automationObject.buttonClearRemarks_

Comment: @AndrewTruckle As of your first comment, is there any example code in VBA! i couldn't understand it exactly . But still that link looks more promising

Comment: See if my answer helps. I don't know what environment I need to try it out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not tested so I will delete it if it is not correct.

From the comments I made it would seem like:

```
Sub CallVSTOMethod()
    Dim addins As COMAddIns
    Set addins = Application.COMAddIns
    Dim addin As COMAddIn
    Set addin = addins.item("CssFillTool")
    addin.ButtonClearRemarks ' cast addin into the correct variable type
End Sub
```

> `ButtonClearRemarks` is one of **many macros** in the addin. When I click that macro seperately it works properly.

But I can't test as I don't have your addin. Since `ButtonClearRemarks` is not part of the base [class](http://ButtonClearRemarks) I assume you need to cast the returned object into **your** addin so that the method is exposed.

You have not shown us the code for `ButtonClearRemarks` so we have limited knowledge to go on.

I also came across [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/office-shared-vba/articles/comaddin-object-property-office) where it suggests:

```
Dim objBaseObject As Object 
Set objBaseObject = _ 
 Application.COMAddIns.Item("CssFillTool").Object
```

So **maybe** you can do it that way.

Comment: I get the following error  _Method or data member not found (Error 461)_ for the last line of the code

Comment: @gowtham Exactly, because that *macro* is not part of the `COMAddin` class. Show us the definition of that macro ...

Comment: So does the error : **Run-time error '91' :Object Variable or with block variable not set** also means the problem is with the COM Add-ins Created

Comment: I would like to send you the code. Is there any other option to send you than uploading it here directly?

Comment: Not sure. You have not shown us anything about this `ButtonClearRemarks ` method.

Comment: yes! regarding that i can send you the VSTO file containing the code. Is there any other option available to send you?

Comment: @gowtham If you provide a skype user name I can connect that way and you send me the file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Add-in in question is COM Visible and the method is accessible, [according to this other accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224306/call-excel-add-in-function-in-macro) (skip the first 2/3 of the answer which mocks up a simple COM Add-in in C# code), you're handling the Add-in incorrectly.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim addin As Office.COMAddIn
    Dim automationObject As Object

    Set addin = Application.COMAddIns("CssFillTool")
    Set automationObject = addin.Object  '<~~ handle the add-in's Object property

    automationObject.ButtonClearRemarks

End Sub
```

Comment: yes, the _automationObject is set to nothing in that line_  i don't know what to do here

Comment: I'd expect a subscript out of range error if CssFillTool isn't a member of the COMAddIns collection, ok. are you sure your AddIn is COM visible?

Comment: addin is = Cssfilltool, but the : _addin.object = nothing_. which is set to automationobject

Comment: can you refer to the other answer to see how to configure the vsto add-in perhaps?